# How come I can't see the unwraped object when in edit mode in UV Editor?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I go to edit mode and I can't see the object on the left side so I don't know how to adjust the texuture.
[image: UV Editing]

Comment: Attached a simple cube file that you unwrap. Then post the file for us to download, so we can see what is going on at your end. I am guessing the unwrapped mesh is 100 times bigger than the image you probably have to zoom out to see it. Since, I don't have your original file. I can't tell if I am correct.

Comment: What happens if you select the mesh in the R/H viewport with 'A'?